# My table did not fit the page in the Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

[image]

I created a presentation in Beamer. But, my table did not fit the page. I have 5 columns and 5 rows. But just 3 rows and columns appear in the page.

Comment: Reduce the amount of text

Comment: More generally, if your data doesn't fit on a slide, you want to put in too much. **Don't** force it in, your slides will be unreadable from the far end of the room/hall.